# Is this sheathed electrical cable burnt?

Tags: electrical

[image]

It just sits under the vapor barrier of insulation and is never touched.

How does this happen??

Comment: That looks like it might have been in contact with the paper backing of the insulation, got moist, then dried; adhering the paper to the cable.

Comment: Can you scrape off any of the back stuff?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 chemicals often found in bathrooms: isopropyl alcohol, and nail polish remover. *Don't* use nail polish remover, it might destroy the wire insulation!

Wet a paper towel with isopropyl alcohol and wipe the brown area repeatedly with it.  See if it comes off onto the paper towel readily, like ink or tar.   If it does, then it's not a scorched wire.

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, this pattern does not look like made by the  heat coming from the internal metal conductor(s) and/or the sheathing layer.

The black area looks like a half loaded container ship with a big (mock?) cannon at the end for defense against pirates near Malakka Street or Somalia.

Those detailing of the edge would be very rare if not impossible after overloading a cable (running in still air), since the heat resp. heat spots would spread the heat more in simple patterns, f.e. by superpositions of more circular burnt areas without those filigree  fingers and rectangular patterns.

But if an insulation did touch the cable with that ship's contact zone, the overheated zone could exactly reflect that contact zone.

It would also be an indication, why the maximal load of a cable is substantially derated if the cable is not run in free air, but next to or in an insulation layer.

Scratching as mentioned by a comment would help for identifying the cause of the color change.

Of course for safety reasons, the cable must not be touched or scratched before it is completely de-energized.

If a supposed burning was not too old, a typical smell should be noticeable.

But It looks more like a "printed" area, not a burnt area.